# Banno - Setting Configuration Values?

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

Our Banno plugin is hosted in a Docker container, which will be deployed in environments shared among our customers. I do not include a config.js file as these values will be unique for each customer. While I can test with a config.js file locally, is there a way to set these values directly from the portal dashboard or in another tool outside of our container? When deploying to a customer, are we able to set these config values ourselves for them?

My other question pertains to any obligations we should adhere to after initiating a new tab using the Banno bridge. For example, are we breaking any rules in enabling voice, video, or desktop functionality on our own site after the redirection?

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to set these values directly from the portal dashboard or in another tool outside of our container? When deploying to a customer, are we able to set these config values ourselves for them?

There is not a concept of stored configuration values from the dashboard. Definitely take a look at our [integration guide](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/guides/launching-your-project/organize-your-integration-guide/) to help onboard your customers.

> are we breaking any rules in enabling voice, video, or desktop functionality on our own site after the redirection?

Once you have directed a user outside of the Banno experience it is totally up to you which tools you enable.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Creating an integration guide to onboard without having access to test the options in that guide is unfortunately not ideal. If there is a workaround or a demo, please let us know.

Is there a Banno code review process at all on our Plugin? If so, what is that process like?

Comment: There isn't any code review process from Jack Henry for plugins. It's between you and the financial institution to decide when you are ready to deploy (with Jack Henry not involved). The philosophy behind this approach is described in our [Open Banking](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/open-banking/) page.

Comment: @JaimeLopezJr. Thank you for the response. In the documentation provided to build a plugin, we create and require a config.js file to access our configuration values.  Given that we will be accessing the config values set up in Banno people, what is the equivalent process to pull those values?

Comment: You'll need to work with the financial institution's admin to get them to share that information with you. That's the other half of the [integration guide](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/guides/launching-your-project/organize-your-integration-guide/) which Sam shared in his answer. One direction is you sharing your config info with the institution, and when they create the External Application and plugin configuration they need to pass info back to you (through some out-of-band process such as a secure email).